# Limiting Access to a Website On Same Server

Tags: security, web, iis, computer-science

Does anyone know if this exact thing would be possible? I've been looking around everywhere but no help. The idea is that we have two sites (we'll call them Websites A and B respectively) residing on two different ports on one server in a network. Website A (designed for the user to go there first) has dual authentication upon the initial login, then has a link to Website B. We want it to work so that a user could not get to Website B without visiting Website A beforehand and logging in to duo. I would think it's somehow possible, given that it's our domain, server, and sites.

Thanks so much! All help is appreciated.

I've tried a lot. However, it's a bit different now, because one of the sites used to be on a different server, but now it's on the same one. I haven't tried anything since they've been on the same server, and I'm not really sure where to start. I've looked at a lot of forums, but no one had my exact problem, so I thought I'd ask.

Comment: What did you do when they were on different servers to stop the user from going directly to the second server?  Why doesn't that work here?

Comment: We don’t actually have anything restricting access to Website B at the moment. We want to wrap dual authentication around it (which it didn’t previously have at all), but for the user to not have to dual authenticate twice - just once with the login of Website A, if that makes sense. So we want the initial dual auth to work for both website A and website B.  So user would login, dual auth, get to website A, then only from website A would they have access to website B.

Answer (score 0):

You can use single sign-on (SSO) solution that supports two-step authentication. This would allow users to log in to Website A using their two-step authentication credentials, and then automatically log them in to Website B without requiring them to enter their credentials again.

The best one for your use case will depend on a **number of factors**, such as the technology stack you are using, your budget, and the specific requirements of your implementation.

Comment: Okay, I will look more into SSO stuff. Thank you so much!!